# Dynamically selecting a twig expression

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a footer on my site which is translated to various languages which looks like this

```
{{ 'footer_text'|trans }}
```

However, there will be various page types with different footers so I want to be able to dynamically set the correct footer, so something like this

```
{{ 'footer_text_{{ page_type_1 }}'|trans }}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about,

```
{{ ('footer_text_' ~ page_type_1) |trans }}
```

---

Good to know,

- `{{ ... }}` twig delimiters can't be nested.
- `~` is used for concatenation.

Comment: That renders as `footer_text_[Translation error for "2"]` If I was to get an error, I'd expect it to be `[Translation error for "footer_text_2"]`

Comment: Check the update, I added parentheses. Now, the translation is applied to the whole string.

Comment: Cheers! Easy when you think about it!